# What is harder to catch, the faster you run?

Tags: riddle

Yet another strange riddle;

> What is harder to catch, the faster you run?

What is the answer?

Comment: Where did you find this riddle? Or did you make it up yourself?

Comment: No, my little brother asked it to me. I can't lose face!

Comment: I see how this could be closed as too broad, but off-topic??? Literally how???

Comment: Yes, I do not understand it much... I already have voted to reopen. Anyone who also thinks this question should not be closed, please add your vote!

Comment: @EgorHans It's an off-topic close reason which essentially means "too broad": see [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1254/5373) for more explanation.

Comment: I concur with @Randal'Thor and as such I'm voting to leave this closed.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I suppose the immediate and obvious answer is

> Breath

Answer (score 48):

While I prefer @Sid's answer, this is also nicely pedantic:

> You are.

Answer (score 6):

> What is harder to catch, the faster you run?

> [The rain.](https://www.sciencefocus.com/planet-earth/do-you-get-wetter-if-you-run-or-walk-in-the-rain/)

Comment: Sometimes. If the wind is blowing from behind, there is an optimal speed - beyond a certain point, the faster you run, the *more* you catch.

Answer (score 4):

> A programming error

because

> debugging while running is hard. Well, it *must* be hard, I haven't tried.

I thought I'd put this for fun, but after I noticed

> op's username

, I think it is a bit more viable

Comment: What was rot13(BC'f hfreanzr) again?

Answer (score 3):

> What is harder to catch, the faster you run?

> [A Cold.]

Comment: There's a better synonym here that doesn't sound like an illness.

Comment: Why? I don't see the connection here.

Comment: @Joshua Yeah, 'A Chill' would have been much better, unsure if it's legit to change for synonyms...

Answer (score 2):

Another viable answer:

> Thrown objects, such as a ball.